# JQueryMobile Datebox and Date Conversion

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, datebox

Is there a way to get the date from the jquerymobile's datebox as Date Object??

Because when I try to get the value of the datebox it comes as string. Later I did some operation to reduce the date by 1 and show it again in the dae box. But it's working in chrome but not in iPad's browser :(
**datebox**

```
<input name="difereddelv"  id="datepickerAct" type="date" data-role="datebox" data-options='{"mode": "calbox"}'> <br/>
```

**button click function**

```
$("#btnPrevDate").bind("click", function(){
    var myDate = $('#datepickerAct').val();
    console.log(myDate);
    var today = new Date(myDate);
    console.log(today);
    today =  new Date(today.getTime() - (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
    console.log(today );
    $('#datepickerAct').val($('#datepickerAct').data('datebox')._formatter('YYYY-mm-DD', today));
    console.log($('#datepickerAct').data('datebox')._formatter('YYYY-MM-DD', today));

 });
```

Can someone tell me please, how to get the date of the datebox and reduce it by 1 and show it again in the datebox textbox??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the date as `Date` object with `$('#myDateInput').data('datebox').theDate;`, where `myDateInput` is the id of your input which has the attribute `data-role="datebox"`.

Comment: To reduce the Date object by one day, you could do `dateObj.setDate(dateObj.getDate()-1);`. To update the date in the datebox component do `$('#myDateInput').trigger('datebox', {'method': 'doset'});`

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, `$('#myDateInput').data('datebox').theDate` did not work for me, but `$('#myDateInput').datebox('getTheDate')` did

Comment: correct.  jQM changed where they store things.  In your first example, if you use 'mobileDatebox' instead of 'datebox', it will still work.  But the second example is more likely to continue working for a long time.